# Несколько Кодировщиков\Раскодировщиков в одной Pipeline Netty

Tags: java, netty

Имеются сервер и клиент на netty.

Задача в том, чтобы они оба могли принимать пакеты двух разных типов и по разному обрабатывать.
Я сделал простенький тестовый пример, чтобы посмотреть как это будет работать, код пример полностью скопирован с [netty user guide](https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html), за исключением инициализации канала, естественно

channel init:

```
public static void init(Channel ch, boolean client /*если true - ответного пакета не последует*/){
    ch.pipeline()
            .addLast("t2_encoder", new T2Encoder())
            .addLast("t1_encoder", new T1Encoder())
            .addLast("t2_decoder", new T2Decoder())
            .addLast("t1_decoder", new T1Decoder())
            .addLast("t2_handler", new T2Handler(client))
            .addLast("t1_handler", new T1Handler(client));
}
```

Как видно есть по два decoder'а, encoder'а и handler'ов.

Общая логика:
t2_decoder при получении сообщения определяет какого оно типа. Если тип2 - декодирует в пакет T2 и пробрасывает, если тип1 - пробрасывает оригинальный ByteBuf, который получил на входе.
t1_decoder просто декодирует полученные сообщения в пакет T1 и пробрасывает
t2_handler и t1_handler получают только сообщения своих типов (согласно документации, что также подтверждают тесты). Если хандлеры серверного типа - они отправляют ответный пакет, в противном случае просто выводят его на экран
t2_encoder и t1_encoder просто пишут пакеты в ByteBuff
Пакеты - простейшие классы с парой полей, который имеют методы write(ByteBuff) и read(ButeBuff) для самоопределения записи\чтения в буфер

В итоге:

- клиент отлично отправляет пакеты T2 и T1, все отлично кодируется, Encoder'ы не конфликтуют
- сервер отлично принимает о обрабатывает так же оба типа пакетов
- сервер без ошибок отправляет ответ на пакет T2 (а клиент его хорошо принимает)
- сервер не может отправить ответ на пакет T1 ([логи сервера](https://pastebin.com/L8gSkLqS), [логи клиента](https://pastebin.com/tg0Wms4W))

Как видно по логам, затык происходит при отправке пакета T1, он даже не попадает ни в один encoder, что вообще очень странно. Еще веселее осознавать тот факт, что pipline клиента и сервера одинаковый, и клиент при этом пакет T1 вполне успешно отправляет.
Более того, ошибка в логах указывает на T2Decoder, и мне совершенно непонятно что забыл декодер в нисходящем pipeline. (при этом в клиенте все еще все работает)

Я в полном замешательстве и вообще не могу понять откуда ноги растут.

Код классов в pipeline: (я не знаю как делать разворачивающиеся спойлеры, подскажите пожалуйста в комментариях)

- [T2Encoder](https://pastebin.com/3EMCwj9Y)
- [T1Encoder](https://pastebin.com/dY1B7Ewa)
- [T2Decoder](https://pastebin.com/UrXKHig5)
- [T1Decoder](https://pastebin.com/GSWtvuL0)
- [T2Handler](https://pastebin.com/q0Giy3VR)
- [T1Handler](https://pastebin.com/5ajEddVd)

Полный код на [github](https://github.com/BlcDragon/netty-test)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, вот ошибки которые, по моему мнению, я допустил:

1. в методе
   `public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception` 
   стоит все же использовать `cause.printStackTrace();`, это позволяет увидеть ошибки.
   Не заметив там отсутствия этой строчки я добрых полтора дня не видел реальных причин.
2. Ошибка которая присутствует выше в логах происходит из-за автоматической попытки Netty вызвать `ReferenceCountUtil.release(Object).`
   Этот метод вызывается каждый раз когда декодер добавляет что-то в out. Вызывается он над объектом, который декодер добавляет в этот список.
   В самой документации указано, что если декодер передает это сообщение выше и оно должно быть обработано где-то еще, то следует использовать метод `ReferenceCountUtil.retain(Object)`
3. Использовать `out.add(in)` с неизмененным буфером нельзя, происходит `DecoderExcpetion`, указывающий на то что декодер добавил объект в `out`, но `reader index` не изменился.
   Естественно при нормальной работе декодера такого не должно происходить (раз что-то декодировали, значит что-то прочитали).
   Вместо `out.add(ByteBuff)`, который я использую в T2Decoder, когда отправляю буфер декодеру T1, следует использовать `ChannelHandlerContext#fireChannelRead(ByteBuff)`

После выполнения вышеизложенных действий клиент и сервер начали принимать друг от друга пакеты обоих типов без ошибок. (код залит в тот же [репозиторий гитхаба](https://github.com/BlcDragon/netty-test))

Возможно у меня все еще есть какие-то ошибки, например утечки памяти.
В этом случае если Вы на них укажете я буду признателен